# never set the container up as 'up' [docker]

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, docker-compose, centos

I made a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` myself and attempted to make containers from the `docker-compose.yml`.
The `apache` container works properly: stable but the `db` container doesn't.
It never becomes the status `up`.

```
/work_space
      |-eccube #docker-compose.yml
      |        #Dockerfile
      |
      |-eccube-data #db
                    #data
                    #ececcube-2.4.1
                    #html
```

Used `docker logs <db container ID>` to see what happened ↓

```sh
Initializing database
2019-05-22T07:59:02.264102Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-05-22T07:59:02.266227Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-05-22T07:59:02.267061Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y sudo
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum clean all
RUN yum -y install wget
RUN yum -y install httpd
RUN yum -y install --enablerepo=remi,remi-php52 php php-devel php-mbstring php-pdo php-gd php-xml php-mcrypt php-pgsql

RUN wget http://downloads.ec-cube.net/src/eccube-2.4.1.tar.gz
RUN tar zxvf eccube-2.4.1.tar.gz

RUN mv -f /eccube-2.4.1/data/ /var/www/data
RUN mv -f /eccube-2.4.1/html/ /var/www/html

RUN rm -rf eccube-2.4.1
RUN rm -rf eccube-2.4.1.tar.gz

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    build: .
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /work_space/eccube-data/html:/var/www/html
      - /work_space/eccube-data/data:/var/www/data
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 6666:3306
    volumes:
      - /work_space/eccube-data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:'cube2_dev'
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

I'll show you code/file you need to figure this out.

```
/w/eccube ❯❯❯ docker ps                                                                                                                                                                                ✘ 1
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
251df77751fe        eccube_apache       "/usr/sbin/httpd -DF…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   eccube_apache_1
/w/eccube ❯❯❯ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                           NAMES
b857c8b211ca        mysql:5.6                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                                   eccube_db_1
251df77751fe        eccube_apache              "/usr/sbin/httpd -DF…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp              eccube_apache_1
```

In var/lib/mysql, these files & dirs exist.

```
root@f4680fa4d3f4:/var/lib/mysql# ls
auto.cnf    ca.pem       client-key.pem  ib_logfile0  ibdata1  mysql           private_key.pem  server-cert.pem  sys
ca-key.pem  client-cert.pem  ib_buffer_pool  ib_logfile1  ibtmp1   performance_schema  public_key.pem   server-key.pem
```

And then, In /work_space/eccube_data/db, indeed, those wewe kind of Synchronized!!!

```
/w/e/db ❯❯❯ ls
auto.cnf           ca.pem             client-key.pem     ib_logfile0        ibdata1            mysql              private_key.pem    server-cert.pem    sys
ca-key.pem         client-cert.pem    ib_buffer_pool     ib_logfile1        ibtmp1             performance_schema public_key.pem     server-key.pem
```

Comment: what does the directory `/work_space/eccube-data/db` contain?

Comment: @Wie Thank you for correcting!

The directory `/work_space/eccube-data/db` contains nothing.

Comment: A debug purpose: Did your `db` container still run after executing your `docker-compose` file? If yes, run `docker exec -it <container-ID> bin/bash ` and go to the directory `var/lib/mysql` and look if there is anything. Additional take a look in runtime in the dir `/work_space/eccube-data/db` on your system (even it should be empty according to your report). 
The idea is to search the file your `db` container believe to see.

Comment: @Wie when i execute my 'docker-compose' file, it seems not to becomes 'up' status: immediately, it becomes 'Exited (1)' status.
I added an explanation in my post above.

Comment: Then try `docker run --privileged -v /work_space/eccube-data/db:/var/lib/mysql -e "MYSQL_DATABASE:'cube2_dev'" -e "LANG=C.UTF-8" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"   -p 6666:3306 mysql:5.7` to look into your dir.

Comment: @Wie I added reports in my post :)
It' amazing! though I'm not sure what should I do next...
by any chance, I should edit a file in `/work_space/eccube-data/db`??

Comment: How is docker installed? (Native Linux, Mac, Windows, Toolbox?) Are you looking at `work_space` within your current folder or on the root of your filesystem?

Comment: @BMitch My local environment is `MacOS` and using `docker for MAC`.
I'm sorry but what is the difference between the current folder and filesystem?
Since I've just started learning to programming, I'd be glad if you could teach me...

Comment: @pop try to use a docker volume for testing without using your file system: Change ` /work_space/eccube-data/db:/var/lib/mysql` e.g. to ` volume_db:/var/lib/mysql` and don't forget to mention your volume at the end of your `docker-compose`. See the (references)[https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Docker for Mac, the following stores data inside the embedded VM since there is no mapping for this directory to your Mac environment:

```
  - /work_space/eccube-data/html:/var/www/html
  - /work_space/eccube-data/data:/var/www/data
```

and

```
  - /work_space/eccube-data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Instead, you want to use relative paths:

```
  - ../eccube-data/html:/var/www/html
  - ../eccube-data/data:/var/www/data
```

and

```
  - ../eccube-data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

This assumes you run your docker-compose commands from inside the `eccube` directory, and that your project is inside the `/Users` directory, which is case sensitive (see more about using other directories in the [Docker for Mac getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#file-sharing)).

Comment: I think you are right in point about the folders from the system not shared with the VM (and at the end with the container). *But:* This does not explain where the files come from.

Comment: @Wie a previous run off the container. Files will get populated inside the embedded VM where they aren't visible to the developer looking at their directories. They also disappear if you restart docker.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had the same thing a few month ago but forget to combine the fact about the vm path and that the path is empty.

Comment: I've actually added the sharing directory '/work_place' through the `Docker for Mac-GUI`.

And I tried what you've taught me, but `db` container still same error and never becomes `up` status...

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `container`, `image` and `volume`, and then executed `docker-compose up -d`.
It worked.
Now I have the containers properly.

Thank you so much!